# Python: Unzip the file, apply modifications on the containing files and zip the file again

Tags: python, xml, xslt, zip

I have to write a filter for files in a zipped file. So I have the zip file as an input, it contains some xml kind of files. I filter the xml with xslt. So the files will be overwritten and finally zip the file again. My code looks like the following:

Problem: Terminates without exceptions but It does not work.

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO
import zipfile

def axlFilter(inputfile):

    with zipfile.ZipFile(inputfile) as zip_file:
      for file in zip_file.namelist():
          try:

              xslt_root = etree.XML('''\
                <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

                <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
                  <xsl:copy>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
                  </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:template>


                <xsl:template match="TimeStamp"/>
                <xsl:template match="@timeStamp"/>
                <xsl:template match="TimeStamps"/>
                <xsl:template match="Signature"/>

                </xsl:stylesheet>
                ''')

              transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_root)

              doc = etree.parse(file)
              result_tree = transform(doc)

              resultfile = StringIO(unicode(str(result_tree)))
              zipwrite.write_file(file, resultfile)


          finally:
              zip_file.close()
```

Comment: Read [this](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/) then refactor your error handling. How's anyone supposed to guess what's going wrong? Assuming `namelist` isn't empty (have you checked that?), anything could be happening.

Comment: Didn't you ask an almost identical question this afternoon where you received -3 (last I checked) votes?  What happened to this question in your profile?  Your current question was asked only 10 min ago, but it seems to be returning the same kind of negative feedback as your first question.

Comment: If I were to run that code, I suspect I would get at least one exception: `NameError: name 'zipwrite' is not defined`